# Adding TabPages with controls inside them dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am trying to add a TabPage and inside it a Textbox.
The problem is if I have more TabPages the content of the TextBox is always the last added and not the selected TabPage.

[image]

**EDIT 3**
//

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int tabcount = 0;
    TextBox TextE;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new textbox to add to each control
        TextE = new TextBox();

        // Fill the tabpage 
       TextE.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
       TextE.Multiline = true;

         // Create new tab page and increment the text of it 
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Text = "Tab" + tabcount.ToString();

        // Add Textbox to the tab
        tab.Controls.Add(TextE);

        // Add tabpage to tabcontrol
        tabControl1.Controls.Add(tab);
        tabcount++;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Text content to messagebox...

        MessageBox.Show(TextE.Text);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the tabs with a number index("Tab01","Tab02", etc.) then cast the current tab as `Scintilla TextEditor`.  Don't get confused by the object name and the Name property.  The controls collection uses the name property as an index key.  so even though you have  objects you've declared with the same name, as long as the name property is different you can add them.

For instance

```
    Scintilla NewTextEditor = new Scintilla();
    NewTextEditor.Name = "tab" + (this.Controls.OfType<Scintilla>.Count + 1).ToString("00");
    this.Controls.Add(NewTextEditor);
```

this will add a new control change the name property so it can be added.

Then  Assuming you have a way of determining the current tab

```
Scintilla TextEditor = CurrentTab;
```

Comment: I tried changing the code as suggested; however, I get an error.

Comment: You're trying to assign a string as a control.  Use the string as the index of the Controls collection and assign that control to the texteditor

Comment: Controls.IndexOf(TextEditor).ToString() always shows -1 now matter how many controls are added. I can't figure out why?

Comment: `Use the string as the index of the Controls collection and assign that control to the texteditor` something like this `TextEditor = doc.Controls["Title1"]`  see how the name string is used as the index..

Comment: Okey I tried to set the Index like so:         private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
        {
          //  Active Tab event        
         tab.Controls.SetChildIndex(TextE, e.TabPageIndex);
        }